# Add new column SUM Money by Name in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sum

Employee table:

```
Name | Can_use | Money    
Jack | Yes     | 1000    
Lara | Yes     | 1500    
Jack | No      | 500    
Jack | Yes     | 700    
Lara | Yes     | 500
```

I want create a View table, with result:

```
Name | Can_use | Money | Sum    
Jack | Yes     | 1000  | 1700    
Lara | Yes     | 1500  | 2000    
Jack | No      | 500   | 1700    
Jack | Yes     | 700   | 1700    
Lara | Yes     | 500   | 2000
```

With Employy "Can_use" = "yes", then Sum += Money

Help me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SUM` window function together with `CASE` will solve your problem.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW yourView AS
SELECT Name,
       Can_use,
       Money,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Can_use = 'Yes' THEN Money ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY Name) "Sum"
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Thanks for help me :)

Comment: Nice comeback, you blew me out of the water +1.